# Api call to all itunes stores

Tags: api, itunes, itunes-store

I'm looking to forward information to my google spreadsheet. Using the documentation for Itunes search on a specific movie, for example I tried, https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=AvengersEndgame&country=US&entity=movie and using a API connector add-on for google spreadsheet, this returned one result for the US store only, based on this movie.
Now adding the same parameters but changing the country code to CA would show the information for the Canada store. https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGy3t.jpg

Now using them together as in 
https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=AvengersEndgame&country=US&entity=movie
https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=AvengersEndgame&country=CA&entity=movie

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQD1U.jpg

it shows two results, nicely, but not always. Somehow it returns an empty .JSON request and I end up questioning why.

When I try to go furthur and add more stores by adding parameters but changing country letters, I end up recieving more and more empty .JSON requests.

That's when I realized I can only get about 20 calls a minute, I did end up being able to call for about 19 stores.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsPHv.jpg with good results.

As there are about a 155 stores in Itunes, I'm looking for a faster way without the hassle of adding 155 of these parameters knowing it will not work as i can only call about 20 results a minute. Could I maybe call in a function to have it search 20 calls every minute untill all 155 are done for which then will be placed in different tabs in a google spreadsheet?

when i try a different movie on Annabelle Comes Home, i end up getting these errors when trying multiple stores.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/34shV.jpg
using only 1 store for example US, shows a correct result. So what causes the error?

Hope someone can help me with this, as I have the parameters but looking for a way to cover all stores and get them on a spreadsheet which i can then furthur edit for a nice list. As not all stores have to be covered, i've broken down the list to 55 stores.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the SO club. Would you please edit your post. Images should be pasted in your post, not linked.